# Allowed Range in case of Date/Timestamp Partitioned table in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

In the google doc I can see the below points about partitioned table :
Streaming into partitioned tables
You can stream data into a table partitioned on a DATE or TIMESTAMP column that is between 5 years in the past and 1 year in the future. Data outside this range is rejected.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery

and in one place it's written :
You can stream data between 1 year in the past and 6 months in the future. Data outside of this range is rejected.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables

I can stream data into bigquery more than 1 year.Can somone please let me know in which context the second one is applicable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The range was previously 1 year in the past and 6 months in the future, but has been expanded to 5 years in the past and 1 year in the future. The second documentation you linked should be updated. Thanks for reporting this problem.